# how to load angularjs custom directive function on initializing page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
angular.module('gdsApp').directive('modalDialog', function($http,$location) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          show: '=',      
          selectFn: '&callbackFn'
        },
        transclude: true, // Insert custom content inside the directive
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            scope.init = function () {
                alert(' inii');
            };
            var urlBase=$location.absUrl().split('/#/')[0]; 
            scope.showLookUpTable = false;

            scope.hideSearchResults = function() {
                scope.showLookUpTable = false;
            };     

        },
        templateUrl: 'pages/LookUpModal.html'
      };
    });
```

```html
<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>
  <div class='ng-modal-overlay'></div>
  <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'
       ng-init="hideSearchResults()">
   <div class='ng-modal-dialog-content'>

      <div class="col-md-12">     
        <h3>Organisation Name Lookup</h3>       
        <hr style="border-top:1px solid darkblue"/>
      </div>      
</div>
```

Hi,
I have `ng-init` function `ng-init=hideSearchResults()`. But the function is not calling while the html page is loading.How to call a function in custom directive from html page on loading.can you please help me.

Comment: It is not wise to have directives changing the global `$http.defaults`.

Comment: Where in the HTML are you instantiating the `modal-dialog` element directive?